# Linking step fails with g++, but works with libtool

Tags: g++, ld, libtool

this is an issue during the linking of a program that includes the gnu plotutils package, specifally the libplotter library.

The "program":

```
#include <plotter.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

complication commands and errors:

```
g++ -c test.cpp -g -O0 -std=c++17
g++ -o test test.o -L/usr/lib64 -lplotter -lxmi

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miDeletePaintedSet(lib_miPaintedSet*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miSetGCPixels(lib_miGC*, int, miPixel const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miSetGCMiterLimit(lib_miGC*, double)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miClearPaintedSet(lib_miPaintedSet*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miCopyPaintedSetToCanvas(lib_miPaintedSet const*, miCanvas*, miPoint)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miSetGCAttrib(lib_miGC*, miGCAttribute, int)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miNewGC(int, miPixel const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miNewCanvas(unsigned int, unsigned int, miPixel)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miNewPaintedSet()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miSetGCAttribs(lib_miGC*, int, miGCAttribute const*, int const*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miDeleteGC(lib_miGC*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miDeleteCanvas(miCanvas*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miSetGCDashes(lib_miGC*, int, unsigned int const*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The missing functions are defined int the libxmi header

```
$ grep miCopyPaintedSetToCanvas /usr/include/ -Rl
/usr/include/xmi.h
```

Both libraries exist in /usr/lib64 (both installed via gentoo linux package manager)

```
$ ls /usr/lib64 | grep -e libplot -e libxmi
libplot.la
libplot.so
libplot.so.2
libplot.so.2.2.4
libplotter.la
libplotter.so
libplotter.so.2
libplotter.so.2.2.4
libxmi.so
libxmi.so.0
libxmi.so.0.1.3
```

The linking works when using libtool though

```
g++ -c test.cpp -g -O0 -std=c++17
libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++  -march=haswell -O2 -pipe -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed  test.o -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXext -lX11  -lpng -lz -lxmi -lm -o test
libtool: link: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -march=haswell -O2 -pipe -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed test.o -o test  -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXext -lX11 -lpng -lz -lxmi -lm
```

Or in verbose

```
libtool: link: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -march=haswell -O2 -pipe -Wl,-O0 -Wl,--as-needed test.o -o test --verbose  -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXext -lX11 -lpng -lz -lxmi -lm
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-10.2.0-r5/work/gcc-10.2.0/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/10.2.0 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/include/g++-v10 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/python --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 10.2.0-r5 p6' --disable-esp --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-multilib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --disable-fixed-point --enable-targets=all --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-libada --disable-systemtap --disable-vtable-verify --disable-libvtv --without-zstd --enable-lto --without-isl --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (Gentoo 10.2.0-r5 p6) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-march=haswell' '-O2' '-pipe' '-o' 'test' '-v' '-shared-libgcc'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/collect2 -plugin /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccxStaDw.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -o test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../.. -O0 --as-needed test.o -lXaw -lXmu -lXt -lSM -lICE -lXext -lX11 -lpng -lz -lxmi -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-march=haswell' '-O2' '-pipe' '-o' 'test' '-v' '-shared-libgcc'
```

I already tested most of the libtool library options in the g++ linking command but this wouldn't fix the g++ linking problem.

Anyway, after the successful linking with libtool, the libplotter library is not listed by ldd:

```
ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffffbda4000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8c8df0a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8c8dd50000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8c8dc1b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8c8e118000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8c8dc01000)
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with the g++ linking command as compared to the working one with libtool?

Thank you

Comment: Have your tried the enabled optimisation -O2? If this is enabled, many unused functions can be omitted and thus, the program successfully linked.

Comment: Now I did, but the result was the same

g++ -o test test.o -L/usr/lib64 -lplotter -lxmi -Wl,-O1 -pipe -Wl,--as-needed -march=haswell -O2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miDeletePaintedSet(lib_miPaintedSet*)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libplotter.so: undefined reference to `miSetGCPixels(lib_miGC*, int, miPixel const*)'

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 18. Even `g++ -o test test.o` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to stack overflow so hope this helps! I ran into the same problem and all I had to was to reinstall ld via this command:

```
sudo apt reinstall binutils
```

If that doesn't work try reinstalling g++ via this command:

```
sudo apt reinstall g++
```